# How show Statically a Picture With Picture Control in MFC?

Tags: mfc, graphic

I Have do Follow :

Drag Picture Control to dialog.
Go to Picture Control propeties.
Change its "Type" to Bitmap.

Then I Add Bitamap ID, and Picture is showed in Picture Control,
But When I Run the Program, nothing show in Picture Control.
Wheres the Problem?

Comment: Did you import bmp file to resources, assign id to it and select this id in picture control?

Comment: Well, it should work. Check properties of picture control, like Visible = true, RealSizeImage=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following procedure to make this work.

First: Add "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Image" Control to the ToolBox.

Second: Drag a "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Image" to Form.

Third: Select That and Add a Picture From Picture Properties.

Is OK and Work 100 Percentage.